# Bukkit - Cannot use external JAR in plugins

Tags: java, jar, classpath, minecraft, bukkit

I am currenly making a plugin for my Bukkit server, and I am unable to use my external libraries; as the server will throw a `NoClassDefFoundError` when loading them. This is because I am using a external library that is not a Bukkit Plugin itself. I really need these libraries because without them, the plugin simply will not work.

**Libraries:** Json Simple, Google GSON (for pretty printing), Apache Commons, and my custom PacketBuffer library.

Comment: use a dependency manager, like maven

Answer (score -2):

Simple JSON and GSON are built-in with Bukkit, not sure about Apache Commons.
If you want to load libraries to plugin/server you can "hack" it with reflections.

Place libraries jar files somewhere accessible by plugin and use `loadFile()` method to load library file.

```
public static void loadFile(File file) throws IOException {
    invokeLoader(file.toURI().toURL());
}

public static void invokeLoader(URL url) throws IOException {
    final URLClassLoader sysloader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    final Class<?> sysclass = URLClassLoader.class;

    try {
        final Method method = sysclass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[] { URL.class });

        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(sysloader, new Object[] { url });
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();

        throw new IOException("Could not add URL to system class loader!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what I was looking for. I am wanting to know how to use ANY library for this project. Such as the Apache Commons for FTP. Not just JSON and GSON.

Comment: Add them to your IDE and load them with code above and use them. What is the problem? You can use ANY library this way.

Comment: The IDE can run the program just fine (When its running in stand-alone version and not plugin version) But when I run it in bukkit, it will not load because it tries to find the class that my Plugin Uses, but cant find it, so it throws the Exception.

Comment: Thats why you need to load the libraries with the method above or use something like maven to compile plugin with libraries.